# mrand not in mingw?

Tags: c

I use dev c++ for my c projects,because it's simple for me.I installed it with the mingw extension.Well,I included stdlib.h and made a call to mrand which according to manpages belongs to that header but I got a linker error.I looked in mingw's headers and found no declaration for mrand although the glibc has one in stdlib.Am I missing something?I thought mingw and gcc were the same.If they are different I suppose that there isn't a way to get gcc's full power.Right?Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to say mrand48.(typo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mrand` is not part of the standard C library, nor is it present in standard Linux manpages. Whatever compiler you previously used may have had it as a proprietary extension, but since you haven't mentioned which (it's not GCC or MSVC, at least), I can't tell what mrand is supposed to do, and so it's hard to suggest an alternative function to use.

Note that glibc *does* offer a `mrand48()`. Since this is a POSIX function, not a standard C function, it may or may not be present in other C libraries - but note that this is a function of the C library (glibc), not the compiler (gcc/mingw).

Comment: My Ide uses mingw so I suppose that my current compiler is gcc.Or at least a minimal version of it.

Comment: Doesn't matter; the key is what C library you're using. I'm not familiar with DevC++, but I doubt it's glibc, as glibc is designed to operate on Unix-like systems, not windows.

Comment: So the only way to access mrand48() would be under gcc.I guess I can't do that in Windows.

Comment: As I said, your compiler (gcc) doesn't matter. If you're using mingw, you're using gcc. The problem is mingw's C library doesn't have `mrand48`. That said, it ought to be simple to reimplement using `long long`s.